# CSS 2 div size auto same height

Tags: html, css, size, width

i have an question in CSS:

How i can do that:

[image: CSS Auto width]

When the green div has (auto) 500px height for the content the red got the same.

And when the red has (auto) 700px height for the content the green got the same.

Both have any content then i use auto height.

So how i can do the green has the same width as red and red too but whit different content whit "height: auto;"?

Comment: This is an article by Matthew James Taylor where he explains this issue and provides an answer. I have used his solution in a couple of my projects and it works beautifully. No JavaScript, no hacks, pure HTML & CSS. [http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just wrap both DIVS, inside another div, and have them bump up on the parent DIV, then resize the parent

Something like this.... then use CSS to format them

```
<div id=parent>
    <div id=child>
      Content....
    </div>
    <div id=child>
      Content....
    </div>
</div>
```

some other solutions could be listed here
http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61

Comment: This one works for me, i used the method whit the image. Thanks you.

Answer (score 5):

First, read [this excellent article](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks). Then, check out the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/qUT3d/

### HTML

```
<div id="container3">
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
            <div id="col2">Column 2</div>
            <div id="col3">Column 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container3 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:72%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:36%;
    position:relative;
    left:76%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd set a min-height on both cells, or as the answer by @Taeeril correctly suggest use javascript to equal out the heights.

Here is a solution using table display types http://jsfiddle.net/SebAshton/Pj7gy/

Answer (score 0):

```
Better solution use both javascript and css.
```

http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc