# 100% height relative to other element

Tags: css, gwt, html, size

Is it possible to make a **div** take 100% height of another non-parent element? 
The objectif is to make a **div** shape automatically, on the size change of another **div**

Comment: May be worth checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113435/css-2-div-size-auto-same-height

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of this being done like so: http://jsfiddle.net/vJvg5/1/

CSS:

```
#content {
    border:solid 1px red;
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
#one {
    border:solid 1px green;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:150px;
    }
#two {
    border:solid 1px blue;
    height:100%;
    width:50px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="one">
    <div id="two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm actually working on a framework so I don't have such flexibility on adding widget anywhere, anyway thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Using GWT you can listen on the [resizeEvent](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ResizeEvent.html) (if it is available on the widgets you are using).

You have [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241084/adding-resize-listener-handler-to-verticalpanel-in-gwt).

CSS is also good.